# How Represent Categorical Data using R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm learning now R programming language and I'm trying to plot a categorial variable called codeCountry which has 50 country codes. I saw all over the internet that you can use the function barplot() to do it, the problem is I can't have a good view of all the country codes. 
I have all my data in a table() object. I have tried to do this:

```
codeCountry<-table(port$code_country)
barplot(codeCountry, main = "Countries", xlab = "Country Code")
```

[image: This is the result I get]

This is the result I get, the problem is I would like to have all the codes avaliables. It is possible to do with R?

Can someone give me some help on this?

Thank you!

Comment: Make the device bigger or the font smaller.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it? I didn't find nothing about that! :S

Comment: Are you saving the plot to a file, or are you displaying it in a window?

Comment: Displaying in a window!

Comment: Do you know how to make a window bigger on a computer?

Comment: What you mean? Increase the width and the height? I tried that I didn't result!

Comment: Make the window wider, don't close the window, and then re-run the plot.

Comment: Thank you! :) That works but depends a lot from the display! :S there is no package that can help on this?

Comment: As a side note: The default font index `par()` value is 1. The `cex` argument specifies the magnification of the label and axis fonts. Try adding arguments `cex.axis = 2` and `cex.lab = 2` to your plot function and observe. Also, 50 categories on x-axis? Try binning them for better readability and comparison.

Comment: also try `horiz=TRUE` as a `barplot` parameter. You can make the y-axis text horizontal as well, but that's a little extra work.

Comment: If you post your data here, there will be more suggestions and also answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My preference is to use ggplot2. A small illustration though.

```
# toy data
set.seed(1)
country = paste0("AAA", sprintf("%02d", 1:50))
population = sample(50:2000, 50)
df = data.frame(country,  population)
# to graph
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = country, y = population)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "grey80", colour = "black", width = 0.4) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-45, hjust=0.001)) # "angle" will tilt the labels
```

[image]